# Said or told? Which one is correct here

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which one is correct? Why?

> "As I said before" 
> OR 
> "As I told before"

Answer (score 2):

Use "said" here. "Told" sounds very awkward. It is [usually used with an indirect object](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/when-do-you-use-said-and-told): "As I told **you** before..." or with certain other forms like "He told **of** his adventure" (old fashioned). "Said" needs a preposition to take another object: "As I said **to** you before..."

Answer (score 1):

"As I said before" is correct, because you are emphasizing or restating that you have already said something, and there is no need to place a noun after "said." "As I told before" is not quite correct, because it raises the question "who have you told before?" "Told" must be followed with an object (noun), because "tell" means that you are speaking to a specific person or audience. In order to "tell" something, you have to have someone around who can listen to what you are saying. "Said" does not need a noun after it because you can say anything, whether or not someone is there to hear it. The correct way to say "As I told before" would be "As I told *you* before" or "As I told *him* before."